# How to delete variabilities from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

Is it possible to delete certain "text" from database which is not static?
For static text I simply replaced "static text" with "".
Actually I just need a command which will delete "static text1 * static text2"
So everything from text1 to text2. 
Text1 and text2 is static, but everything between changes.

Thanks for help

Comment: I can't follow your question. Are you asking how to delete a row from a table, or how to update a cell/column in a given table? Can you give examples of your current data and what you need to "happen"?

Comment: I need to delete text from specific column in multiple rows.
But the problem is that text is different from each column, and some text is the same. So I need to delete everything from "same text" till another "same text" in all rows.
Hope I have explained it better since I'm really bad with mysql :/

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?  Are you storing a list of items in a delimited string?  Are you processing markup?

Comment: No, I'm editing huge wordpress database and I want to delete some stuff from all posts at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to `UPDATE` a text-value in a table to remove any text that's between `text1` and `text2`, but leave the actual row in-tact.

If that's the case, you can use a combination of `SUBSTRING()` and `LOCATE()` to perform the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE your_table SET
    field = 
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(field, 1, LOCATE('text1', field) + 5),
            SUBSTRING(field, LOCATE('text2', field))
        )
WHERE
    field LIKE '%text1%text2%'
```

This will take the first part of the `field` column up-to the text "text1" (and including the `text1` text itself), then will take a second sub-string from the `field` column for everything *after* (and including) the `text2` text.

If you want to "change" the text in-between these two values, for instance say you have `text1 some-value text2` and you want it to become `text1 new-thing text2`, you could use the above query and put the new text in the middle:

```
UPDATE your_table SET
    field = 
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(field, 1, LOCATE('text1', field) + 5),
            ' new-thing ',
            SUBSTRING(field, LOCATE('text2', field))
        )
WHERE
    field LIKE '%text1%text2%'
```

Comment: [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) takes three arguments.  I think you may have intended to use `1` and `-1` as the third, ***`count`*** argument in your respective calls: but then why use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)?  Or did you mean to use [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)?

Comment: @eggyal You're absolutely right - I was thinking of a different language entirely! I've updated to use MySQL's `LOCATE()` as it accomplishes the goal I was aiming for. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about deleting entire rows based on finding the pattern of "static text1", followed by anything, and followed by "static text2", try (replacing `myTable` and `myRow` with your values):

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myRow` LIKE 'static text1%static text2';
```

If this returns the rows you want to delete, you can run the delete command:

```
DELETE FROM `myTable` WHERE `myRow` LIKE 'static text1%static text2';
```